# Integral of the integral using NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, syntax

Consider the integral

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, y}]], {y, 0, 2.8}]
```

It displays an error `x = y is not a valid limit of integration`, however, gives some number. What is a reason for the error and how to interpret the numeric result?

Of course, I can easily replace the integration symbol in the exponent by the value of the integral, however, this is only a toy example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Of course you cannot perform the inner *numerical* integral with an un-specified (free) variable.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : however, it turned out that Mathematica gives the correct answer. Why this is possible?

Comment: Hmmm.... a tricky question about the internal methods of *Mathematica*.  Frankly, I don't know why the correct answer is given (despite the error messages).

Comment: Mathematica does not _have_ to evaluate the integrand symbolically, in order to apply numerical quadrature. However, it does so usually in order to analyze the integrand. If it fails, it throws an error and tries purely numerical methods. This why it works in the end.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm wondering if I turn off `SymbolicProcessing`, would this error still present?

Comment: @Turgon How would you do that? `SymbolicProcessing` is not an option of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher actually it is an option of `NIntegrate`. Check the help page, it's under Options->Method->SymbolicProcessing.

Comment: @Turgo Ah, you mean `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}`. Yes. Unfortunately, that does not remove the error messages.

Comment: Using `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}` indeed does not  eliminate the error messages, but does reduce the number of them to two when applied to the outer integration.  It seems to have no effect on the inner integration.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037,
esp. ref. [6)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135130/a-nintegrate-in-the-nintegrate/135164#135164) under `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try to restrict the definition of the integrand to avoid symbolic calculation. Like:

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := Exp[-NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, y}]];
NIntegrate[f[y], {y, 0, 2.8}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a refinement of bbgodfrey's approach, where I combine both integrals into a single [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) call:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    z'[x] == x, z[0]==0,
    int'[x] == Exp[-z[x]], int[0]==0
    },
    int,
    {x, 0, 2.8}
];
sol[2.8] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.*10^-6, 1.24691}

The nice thing about this approach is that computing the integral for various `y` limits is quick. Compare this timing to that of the other numerically based answers:

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := Exp[-NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, y}]];
NIntegrate[f[y], {y, 0, 2.8}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.072347, 1.24691}

```
NDSolveValue[{z'[x] == x, z[0] == 0}, z[x], {x, 0, 2.8}];
NIntegrate[Exp[-%], {x, 0, 2.8}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.026102, 1.24691}

Comment: Your approach indeed is much faster than mine (about a factor of eight, +1), but not by as much as your answer suggests.  `AbsoluteTiming` as applied in your answer determines only the time required to evaluate `sol[2.8]`, but omits the time required to compute the interpolation function `sol` itself.

Answer (score 4):

A typically more efficient approach for complicated integrands is

```
NDSolveValue[{z'[x] == x, z[0] == 0}, z[x], {x, 0, 2.8}];
NIntegrate[Exp[-%], {x, 0, 2.8}]
(* 1.24691 *)
```

The inner integration is performed only once here.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you cannot perform the inner *numerical* integral with an un-specified (free) variable, $y$.

Why not simply perform the analytic integrals and be done with it?

```
Integrate[Exp[-Integrate[x, {x, 0, y}]], {y, 0, 2.8}]
```

$1.24691$

Comment: I have used this simple integral as an example. Realistic integrals I want to use are much more complicated.

Comment: @JohnTaylor:  How do you know your "more complicated" integrals cannot be computed analytically?

Answer (score 3):

A few comments to the posted comments and answers follow.

### Faster computations without messages

> @Turgo Ah, you mean Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}. Yes. Unfortunately, that does not remove the error messages. – Henrik Schumacher Jul 27 at 13:57
>
> Using Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False} indeed does not eliminate the error messages, but does reduce the number of them to two when applied to the outer integration. It seems to have no effect on the inner integration. – bbgodfrey Jul 27 at 18:32

Here is a definition that produces faster results without messages. The setting
`Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` is used for both integrals.

```
Clear[f];
f[y_?NumericQ] := 
  Exp[-NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, y}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = NIntegrate[f[y], {y, 0, 2.8}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
 ]

(* {0.00553, 1.24691} *)
```

### Precision of the results

OP says the computation in his post is a simplified example of a computation with more complicated integrands. Depending on the integrands and precision goal requirements [the `NDSolve` approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202850/34008)
might be not precise enough.

Illustrating computations follow. (I show `WorkingPrecision->30` and `PrecisionGoal->20`, but similar results are obtained with machine precision and `PrecisionGoal->12`.)

#### `Integrate`

```
F[y0_] := Integrate[Exp[-Integrate[x, {x, 0, y}]], {y, 0, y0}]
F[y0] 
(* Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Erf[y0/Sqrt[2]] *)

F[2.8]
(* 1.24691 *)
```

#### `NDSolve`:

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{z'[x] == x, z[0] == 0, int'[x] == Exp[-z[x]], 
    int[0] == 0}, int, {x, 0, 28/10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 20];
sol2[28/10]

(* 1.24690937538389563405549789088 *)

Abs[sol2[2.8] - F[28/10]]

(* 1.33227*10^-14 *)
```

#### `NIntegrate`

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := 
  Exp[-NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, y}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 20]];
res = NIntegrate[f[y], {y, 0, 28/10}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 20]

(* 1.24690937538388234380595431698 *)

Abs[res - F[28/10]]

(* 0.*10^-30 *)
```